# Proof that a set of functions are independent

Tags: linear-algebra

The problem is an outline of a proof by induction for the following.
Give $r_1,\dots,r_n$ distinct real numbers, $Q_1,\dots,Q_n$ be $n$ polynomials, none of which is the zero polynomial, prove that $Q_1e^{r_1x},\dots,Q_ne^{r_nx}$ are independent. So the problem asks that you do this by, knowing that it is true for $n=1$,$n=2$, assuming the statement true for $n=p$, and then proving $\sum_{k=1}^{p+1} c_kQ_k(x)e^{r_kx} = 0$ by multiplying the sum by $e^{-r_{p+1}x}$ and then differentiating, then using the inductive hypothesis to show all $c_k=0$.

When I differentiate the sum I get:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{p+1}\frac{d}{dx}c_kQ_k(x)e^{(r_k-r_{p+1})x} = \left(\sum_{k=1}^p c_ke^{(r_k-r_{p+1})x}((r_k-r_{p+1})Q_k(x)+Q'_k(x))\right)+c_{p+1}Q'_{p+1}(x) = 0
$$
and I'm not sure how to bring the inductive hypothesis into play.

Answer (score 4):

Without loss of generality suppose $r_{p+1}>r_i$ and then
$$\sum_{k=1}^{p+1} c_kQ_k(x)e^{r_kx} = 0\iff e^{r_{p+1}x}\sum_{k=1}^{p+1} c_kQ_k(x)e^{(r_k-r_{p+1})x}=0 \iff \sum_{k=1}^{p+1} c_kQ_k(x)e^{(r_k-r_{p+1})x}=0$$
and by passing to the limit $x\to+\infty$ we find $c_{p+1}=0$. Now use the inductive hypothesis.

Answer (score 2):

Keep differentiating until $Q_{p+1}$ vanishes, then use the inductive hypothesis!